# How to Generate Swatch Library from Json file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-scripting, color-spaces

I'm looking for a way to generate a swatch library from a JSON file in Adobe Photoshop CS6. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find anything on the web about this, and I don't know how to write my own plugin/script that will do this for me.

If there is a free script/plugin out there that will do this can you please send me the link. If nothing exists can you direct me to a place where I can find a template for a Photoshop CS6 script and to some sample code that can make a swatch from a given name and RGB values?

Comment: What's the JSON look like?

Answer (score 1):

An old question but maybe this will help to someone. Scripting on a basic level is *very* simple in Phootshop and usually comes down to several steps:

- If you have no idea about Javascript you go to code academy, udemy or whatever site you like and learn basic things like variables, arrays and functions — this will take only several hours;
- you download and install [ScriptingListener plug-in](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/downloadable-plugins-and-content.html#ScriptingListenerplugin). This plugin records *most* of the things that happen in Photoshop as javascript code that looks ugly but who cares;
- you google the things you don't understand or don't know (like how to read a json file) — javascript is very popular, if you want to do something there were thousands people who tried to do the same;
- you wrap this all to a script.

For instance. If I create a new Swatch, ScriptingListener will record this code to a log file on Desktop:

```
// =======================================================
var idMk = charIDToTypeID( "Mk  " );
    var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
        var ref1 = new ActionReference();
        var idClrs = charIDToTypeID( "Clrs" );
        ref1.putClass( idClrs );
    desc4.putReference( idnull, ref1 );
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID( "Usng" );
        var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
        var idNm = charIDToTypeID( "Nm  " );
        desc5.putString( idNm, "my swatch" );
        var idClr = charIDToTypeID( "Clr " );
            var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
            var idRd = charIDToTypeID( "Rd  " );
            desc6.putDouble( idRd, 62.000000 );
            var idGrn = charIDToTypeID( "Grn " );
            desc6.putDouble( idGrn, 62.000000 );
            var idBl = charIDToTypeID( "Bl  " );
            desc6.putDouble( idBl, 62.000000 );
        var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID( "RGBC" );
        desc5.putObject( idClr, idRGBC, desc6 );
    var idClrs = charIDToTypeID( "Clrs" );
    desc4.putObject( idUsng, idClrs, desc5 );
    var idpushToDesignLibraries = stringIDToTypeID( "pushToDesignLibraries" );
    desc4.putBoolean( idpushToDesignLibraries, false );
executeAction( idMk, desc4, DialogModes.NO );
```

while it's very difficult to read you can see that there're three values for RGB colors and there's a name field that has a `my swatch` string. So I can wrap this to a function and forget about it:

```
function createNewSwatch(name, red, green, blue)
{
  // =======================================================
  var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
  var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
  var ref1 = new ActionReference();
  var idClrs = charIDToTypeID("Clrs");
  ref1.putClass(idClrs);
  desc4.putReference(idnull, ref1);
  var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
  var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idNm = charIDToTypeID("Nm  ");
  desc5.putString(idNm, name); // here goes a name property
  var idClr = charIDToTypeID("Clr ");
  var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var idRd = charIDToTypeID("Rd  ");
  desc6.putDouble(idRd, red); // red goes here
  var idGrn = charIDToTypeID("Grn ");
  desc6.putDouble(idGrn, green); // green goes here
  var idBl = charIDToTypeID("Bl  ");
  desc6.putDouble(idBl, blue); // blue goes here
  var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID("RGBC");
  desc5.putObject(idClr, idRGBC, desc6);
  var idClrs = charIDToTypeID("Clrs");
  desc4.putObject(idUsng, idClrs, desc5);
  var idpushToDesignLibraries = stringIDToTypeID("pushToDesignLibraries");
  desc4.putBoolean(idpushToDesignLibraries, false);
  executeAction(idMk, desc4, DialogModes.NO);
}
```

so later we can do something like `createNewSwatch('cool swatch', 255, 0, 0);` to create a new red swatch.

Reading a json depends on how the json looks like. If it's a plain json like this:

```
var data = {
  colors: [
  {
    name: "calming grey",
    color: [92, 94, 104]
  },{
    name: "alarming grey",
    color: [54, 42, 42]
  },]
}
```

we can simply eval this file:

```
$.evalFile('/E/temp/temp_js/myjson.json')
alert(data); // will alert [Object]
```

if it's stringified like this:

```
{"colors":[{"name":"calming grey","color":[92,94,104]},{"name":"alarming grey","color":[54,42,42]}]}
```

we'll need to include a json library that you can [find on the internets](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/master/json2.js) to read and parse the file. But how do we read a file? [We google that](https://www.joshwright.com/tips/reading-and-writing-text-files-from-photoshop-scripts) and wrap in a function, something like that:

```
function readFile(link) {
    var b = new File(link);
    b.open('r');
    var str = "";
    while(!b.eof)
    str += b.readln();
    b.close();
    return str
}
```

Now we have everything we need, so we just make a loop to go through all the colors of the json:

```
// to include json library
//@include "json2.js"

function main()
{

  try
  {
    var data = readFile('/E/temp/temp_js/myjson-string.json');
  }
  catch (e)
  {
    alert(e);
    return false; // if file isn't found, terminate
  }

  var dataObject = JSON.parse(data); // parse string to an object

  //for each element of my dataObject.color array:
  for (var i = 0; i < dataObject.colors.length; i++)
  {
    // create a new swatch with element name and element color
    createNewSwatch(dataObject.colors[i].name,
      dataObject.colors[i].color[0],
      dataObject.colors[i].color[1],
      dataObject.colors[i].color[2])
  }

  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  // function to read a file
  function readFile(link)
  {
    var b = new File(link);
    if (!b.exists) throw 'File ' + link + ' not found';
    b.open('r');
    var str = "";
    while (!b.eof)
      str += b.readln();
    b.close();
    return str
  }

  //function to create a swatch
  function createNewSwatch(name, red, green, blue)
  {
    // =======================================================
    var idMk = charIDToTypeID("Mk  ");
    var desc4 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idnull = charIDToTypeID("null");
    var ref1 = new ActionReference();
    var idClrs = charIDToTypeID("Clrs");
    ref1.putClass(idClrs);
    desc4.putReference(idnull, ref1);
    var idUsng = charIDToTypeID("Usng");
    var desc5 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idNm = charIDToTypeID("Nm  ");
    desc5.putString(idNm, name);
    var idClr = charIDToTypeID("Clr ");
    var desc6 = new ActionDescriptor();
    var idRd = charIDToTypeID("Rd  ");
    desc6.putDouble(idRd, red);
    var idGrn = charIDToTypeID("Grn ");
    desc6.putDouble(idGrn, green);
    var idBl = charIDToTypeID("Bl  ");
    desc6.putDouble(idBl, blue);
    var idRGBC = charIDToTypeID("RGBC");
    desc5.putObject(idClr, idRGBC, desc6);
    var idClrs = charIDToTypeID("Clrs");
    desc4.putObject(idUsng, idClrs, desc5);
    var idpushToDesignLibraries = stringIDToTypeID("pushToDesignLibraries");
    desc4.putBoolean(idpushToDesignLibraries, false);
    executeAction(idMk, desc4, DialogModes.NO);
  }

}
main()
```